# Unable to push_back float64 custom msg in std::vector<std_msgs::Float64>

Tags: ros, std-msgs, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom message as follows:

```
sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 velodynepoints 
float64[3] velodynenormal
```

and a subscriber nodelet with the following callback function

```
void class_name::func_name(const pkg_name::msg_file_name::ConstPtr &data) 
{
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
velodyne_n.push_back(data->velodynenormal[i]);
}
}
```

where `velodyne_n` is `std::vector< std_msgs::Float64 > velodyne_n;`
However, I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std_msgs::Float64_<std::allocator<void> > >::push_back(const double&)’
 velodyne_n.push_back(data->velodynenormal[i]);
                                             ^
```

but if I define `velodyne_n` as `std::vector<float> velodyne_n`, I get no errors. Can someone help in pointing out where I might be going wrong? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307760/unable-to-push_back-float64-custom-msg-in-std::vector%3Cstd_msgs::float64%3E/) by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The datatype `std_msgs::Float64` is not the same as a c++ 64 bit float (double). It is a message object that contains a member called `data` which is a 64bit float type.

To add a `std_msgs::Float64` to the `velodyne_n` vector you'll need to create a `std_msgs::Float64` object set it's `data` member to one of the values from `velodynenormal` then push_back that object.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2018-11-06**:
Thank you! I thought `float64` in the custom message was of the type `std_msgs::Float64`

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-07**:
I can see how that might be unclear. Glad you got this working